# DyGraph and Dropbox

Tags: html, r, shiny, dropbox, dygraphs

I created a MULTIPLE DyGraph's (10 of them) in R and I'd like to embed these into an HTML page (which I have done using `<iframe id="iframe"` - perhaps the easiest method) and publish these from my DROPBOX (the main ISSUE). I tried Rdrop2 but was not able to get my head around. Can anyone help??`

R CODE HERE

```
        dygraph(cbind1, main = "General and Acute Bed Capacity") %>%
          dySeries("East_and_North_Hertfordshire", axis = 'y', strokeWidth = 2, strokePattern = "dotted" ) %>%
          dySeries("Hertfordshire_Community", axis = 'y', strokeWidth = 2, strokePattern = "dotdash") %>%
          dySeries("Luton_and_Dunstable", axis = 'y', strokeWidth = 2, strokePattern = 3:7) %>%
          dySeries("West_Hertfordshire", axis = 'y', strokeWidth = 2, strokePattern = "dashed") %>%
          dySeries("Overall_Bed_Capacity", axis = 'y2', strokeWidth = 2, fillGraph = TRUE) %>%
          dyAxis("y", label = "Individual Trust - Bed Capacity", c(100, 1200)) %>%
          dyAxis("y2", label = "Health Economy - Bed Capacity", independentTicks = TRUE, , valueRange = c(1500, 2600)) %>%
          dyAxis("x", label = "Data source: Quarterly Bed Availability and Occupancy www.england.nhs.uk") %>%
          dyLegend(show = "always", labelsSeparateLines = TRUE, hideOnMouseOut = TRUE, width = 250)%>% 
          dyOptions(fillAlpha = 0.3, digitsAfterDecimal = 0, colors = c('darkorange', 'magenta', 'darkred', 'yellowgreen','steelblue'),  drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 3, drawGrid = FALSE)
```

HTML CODE (Partial)

```
        <iframe id="iframe" width=1300 height=520 src="file:///C:/Users/Owner/Dropbox/NHS.htm" style="border:5px dotted red"></iframe>
```

Comment: You can only embed it to a Shiny application, not a regular webpage, as the R code needs an R backend to process

Comment: You can render them into HTML with `knitr` or `htmlwidgets`, but Dropbox isn't very good at rendering the resulting file, likely because they don't want to run JavaScript that people upload (same for Github Pages). People can still download the files and open them in a browser, but the graphs won't be visible on the web. If you want them to be, use `knitr` with [rpubs](http://rpubs.com/) (simple) or `shiny` with [shinyapps.io](http://www.shinyapps.io/) (can be made fancy).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your kind answers. I found a way around to host my DyGraph blog post through google drive. I felt Dropbox's Rdrop2 feature wasnt helping me much.